# iOS - Scheduled background task

Tags: ios, swift, background, scheduled-tasks

In my application, I get two parameters from the server. These are `frequency` and `startTime`.
My task is to start the task at the `startTme` and execute it with the specified `frequency`.

Example:
at 11.00 I get from the server `startTime: 15.30` and `frequency: 5`
After that, the user will close the application.
And at 15:30 the application should start the task (find out and send the current location) and repeat this(every 5 min) until a certain time.

Question:
I am trying to use BGTaskScheduler for this, but so far there are no results.
Please tell me how I can do this and is it real at all?

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot launch every 5 minutes or ensure that a task happens at a specific time. You will need to redesign. If you need to track locations, see Core Location, which may provide you what you want (in particular look at `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, which may address your issue). You can also look at push notifications, where the server would request the app be launched at 15:30. There are intentional restrictions on all of these techniques, however. "Run whenever an app wants" is not a thing on iOS.

Comment: [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063/) is probably good primer on background execution. Unfortunately, neither "run at a certain time" nor "repeat every x minutes" are viable patterns. But you can get background [location updates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location) using standard change service, significant change service, or visits service, all outlined in the above link. Standard change service is the most accurate, but drains the battery quickly, which is why we have the other two.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The task of getting the location is not a problem, I use a plugin for that.
But starting it in the background is really a challenge.
Thanks)